# How can I change the background image to a different image each time I click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, background-image

I'm using `jQuery` to try to change the `background-image` each time I click a button. Currently my background is going through a `for` loop each time the button is clicked, so the picture is going straight from the first picture to the last picture in my folder.

I know this is not what I'm aiming for but this is the only thing I've been able to get work without throwing errors:

```
$('#bg-change').on('click', function() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    $('#background').css('background-image', 'url("./img/blank-wall'+i+'.jpg"')
  };
});
```

I've tried using an array as well as toggling classes but it can only get it to change between two images.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `for` loop you can just use a counter variable and an `if` statement and it should work.

```
let imgIndex = 0;

$('#bg-change').on('click', function() {
  imgIndex ++;

  if (imgIndex > 4) {
    imgIndex = 1;
  }

  $('#background').css('background-image', 'url("./img/blank-wall'+imgIndex+'.jpg"')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let num = 1 // Counter
const picNum = 5 // Number of images in a folder
$('#bg-change').on('click', function() {
  if (num == picNum){
    num = 1
  }else {
     num += 1
  }
  $('#background').css('background-image', 'url("./img/blank-wall'+num+'.jpg"')
});
```

At first you should specify the number of images then define a variable (num) that each time when you click the button add 1 to it or if that was equal to the number of images simply redefine it as 1 then it can change the background by the value of `num` variable.